# C++20 stopping a detached std::jthread using an std::stop_token

Tags: c++, multithreading, std, c++20

In C++20 `std::jthread` was introduced as a safer version of `std::thread`; where `std::jthread`, as far as I understand, cleans up after itself when the thread exits.

Also, the concept of cooperative cancellation is introduced such that an `std::jthread` manages an `std::stop_source` that handles the state of the underlying thread, this `std::stop_source` exposes an `std::stop_token` that outsiders can use to read the state of the thread sanely.

What I have is something like this.

```cpp
class foo {
  std::stop_token stok;
  std::stop_source ssource;

public:
  void start_foo() {
    // ...
    auto calculation = [this](std::stop_token inner_tok) {
      // ... (*this is used here)
      while(!inner_tok.stop_requested()) {
        // stuff
      }
    }
    auto thread = std::jthread(calculation);
    ctok = thread.get_stop_token();
    ssource = thread.get_stop_source();

    thread.detach(); // ??
  }

  void stop_foo() {
    if (ssource.stop_possible()) {
      ssource.request_stop();
    }
  }

  ~foo() {
   stop_foo();
  }
}
```

**Note** `foo` is managed by a `std::shared_ptr`, and there is no public constructor.

Somewhere along the line, another thread can call `foo::stop_foo()` on a possibly detached thread.

Is what I am doing safe?

Also, when detaching a thread, the C++ handle is no longer associated with the running thread, and the OS manages it, but does the thread keep receiving stop notifications from the `std::stop_source`?

Is there a better way to achieve what I need? In MVSC, this doesn't seem to raise any exceptions or halt program execution, and I've done a lot of testing to verify this.

So, is this solution portable?

Comment: "*Is what I am doing safe?*" - think what would happen if `start_foo()` were called more than once on the same `foo` instance. "*does the thread keep receiving stop notifications from the std::stop_source*" - `stop_source` holds a shared state. You and the detached thread are holding `stop_source` objects that are sharing a single state. So yes, you can still signal the detached thread as long as it is running.

Comment: Unrelated: Why detach it? You seem to want to take care so that it's stopped when a `foo` goes out of scope, so why not let the `jthread` do it's thing?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Detaching the thread prevents it from being automatically stopped when `foo::stop_foo` goes out of scope. As for the call in the destructor I can't be sure if the thread finishes before the `foo` instance is destroyed.

Comment: @HashAL78 That's sort of my point. You tell it to stop, but you can't join it to make sure it's stopped (unless you add some method of making sure yourself). I guess I have never understood what's so great about detached threads. It just makes everything more complicated i.m.o., not less.

Comment: @HashAL78 "*Detaching the thread prevents it from being automatically stopped when `foo::stop_foo` goes out of scope*" - you meant `start_foo()` instead. In any case, that issue is only because you are declaring `thread` as a local variable of `start_foo()`. If you were to store it as a class member instead (as you are for the `stop_source` and `stop_token`, which could then move into `stop_foo()` as local variables), then detaching is no longer an issue. `stop_foo()` can still stop the thread if it is running, and `~foo()` can `join()` the thread after stopping it to make sure it ends cleanly

Comment: @HashAL78 and, you now get the added benefit that `start_foo` will have access to an existing thread as a class member, so it can choose whether to exit/throw if a thread is already running, or it can create a new thread and stop the old thread, or even track multiple threads in an array/vector, etc. So, making the `jthread` be a class member gives you more options, without sacrificing any.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo I need my main thread to continue executing and not get blocked on `calculation`. I see your point though, what if I used a normal `std::thread` and an `std::atomic_flag`?,I would assume that would remove my need for detaching the thread and fighting `std::jthread`s implementation, but I believe I need to implement pausing in the future and `std::jthread` integrates well with `std::condition_variable`. I am not sure I get you when you say "you can't join it", isn't this why detaching is needed? I just want my task to run concurrently but still have the ability to stop it if I want.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I haven't thought of that actually (storing the thread instance in `foo`). blahh I need some coffee.

Comment: @HashAL78 "*I need my main thread to continue executing and not get blocked on `calculation`*" - nothing Ted said would cause that to happen even if you don't detach the thread. Basically, that could only happen if the main thread tries to `join()` the `jthread` but the `jthread` doesn't end (ie because of a deadlock for instance).

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote is potentially unsafe if the thread accesses `this` after the `foo` has been destroyed.  It's also a bit convoluted.  A simpler approach would just be to stick the jthread in the structure...

```
class foo {
  std::jthread thr;

public:
  void start_foo() {
    // ...
    jthr = std::jthread([this](std::stop_token inner_tok) {
      // ... (*this is used here)
      while(!inner_tok.stop_requested()) {
        // stuff
      }
    });
  }

  void stop_foo() {
    jthr.request_stop();
  }

  ~foo() {
     stop_foo();
     // jthr.detatch(); // this is a bad idea
  }
}
```

To match the semantics of your code, you would uncomment the `jthr.detach()` in the destructor, but this is actually a bad idea since then you could end up destroying `foo` while the thread is still accessing it.  The code I wrote above is safe, but obviously whichever thread drops the last reference to the `foo` will have to wait for the `jthread` to exit.  If that's really intolerable, then maybe you want to change the API to stick a `shared_ptr` in the thread itself, so that the thread can destroy `foo` if it is still running after the last external reference is dropped.